# What is the most efficient way to record JSON data per second

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, cron

**Reason**

I've been building a system that pulls data from multiple JSON sources. The data being pulled is constantly changing and I'm recording what the changes are to a SQL database via a PHP script. 9 times out of 10 the data is different and therefore needs recording.

The JSON needs to be checked every single second. I've been successfully using a cron task every minute with a PHP function that loops 60 times over.

The problem I'm now having is that the more JSON sources I want to check the slower the PHP file runs, meaning the next cron get's triggered before the previous has finished. It's all starting to feel way too unstable and hacky.

---

**Question**

Assuming the PHP script is already the most efficient it can be, what else can be done?

- Should I be using multiple cron tasks?
- Should something else other then PHP be used?
- Are cron tasks even suitable for this sort of problem?

Any experience, best practices or just plan old help will be very much appreciated.

---

**Overview**

I'm monitoring for active race sessions and recording each driver and then each lap a driver completes. Laps are recorded only once a driver crosses the start/finish line and I do not know when race sessions may or may not be active or when a driver crosses the line. Therefore I have been checking every second for new data to record.

Each venue where a race session may be active has a separate URL to receive JSON data from. The more venue's I add to my system to monitor the slower the script takes to run.

I've currently 19 venues and the script takes circa 12 seconds to complete. Since I'm running a cron job every minute and looping the script every second. I'm assuming I have at the very least 12 scripts running every second. It just doesn't seem like the most efficient way to do it to me. Of course, it worked a charm back when I was only checking 1 single venue.

Comment: Look into using queues, each worker handles an API.

Comment: Admittedly i have very low understanding of cron queues, however, surely there is a risk of missing out on data if a cron task is waiting on another to finish?

Comment: I was suggesting move away from cron and use a queue system like rabbitmq, gearman, beanstalked. Something with workers and a broker, you can place triggering tasks for the workers to do by cron or other means.

Comment: Oh sorry, i totally miss read your suggestion then!

That sounds like a much much more efficient way indeed. I appreciate the response.

Comment: what if you use an infinite loop? `while(true){ // pull from source }` . This way, when one pull is finished, the next will come

Comment: What's the consequence of being late--or early--checking any given JSON source? How badly is your system damaged if you check some source after 80 seconds, or after 50, rather than 60?  How much does it matter if some sources are checked at 10 seconds after the top of the minute and others at 30 seconds? In other words how tolerant is your system to variable sampling rates and sampling jitter?

Comment: How bad is it if you take your samples on time but they don't make it into your database for an unpredictable amount of time? Do you have peak-load times of day when more stuff changes from sample to sample?

Comment: So long as the data isn't missed it's not massively important that it isn't recorded onto the database instantly. I've updated my question and added information on what i'm trying to do.

I do provide a live feed for watching laps as they happen along side recording each one, but I can get the live data directly from a single source rather then waiting on my script to record laps and pulling it back down again.

Answer (score 0):

There's a cycle to your operations.  It is.

1. start your process by reading the time witn `$starttime = time();`.
2. compute the next scheduled time by taking the time plus 60 seconds. `$nexttime = $starttime + 60;`
3. do the operations you must do (read a mess of json feeds)
4. compute how long is left in the minute  `$timeleft = $nexttime - time();`.
5. sleep until the next scheduled time `if ($timeleft > 0) sleep ($timeleft);`
6. set `$starttime = $nexttime`.
7. jump back to step 2.

Obviously, if `$timeleft` is ever negative, you're not keeping up with your measurements. If `$timeleft` is always negative, you will get further and further behind.

The use of `cron` every minute is probably wasteful, because it takes resources to fire up a new process and get it going. You probably want to make your process run forever, and use a shell script that monitors it and restarts it if it crashes.

This is all pretty obvious.  What's not so obvious is that you should keep track of your individual `$timeleft` values for each minute over your cycle of measurements.  If they vary daily, you should track for a whole day. If they vary weekly you should track for a week.

Then you should should look at the worst (smallest) values of `$timeleft`. If your 95th percentile is less than about 15 seconds, you're running out of resources and you need to take action. You need a margin like 15 seconds, so your system doesn't move into overload.

If your system has zero tolerance for late sampling of data, you should look at the single worst value of `$timeleft`, not the 95th percentile. You should give yourself a more generous margin than 15 seconds.

So-called *hard real time* systems allocate a time slot to each operation, and crash if the operation exceeds the time slot. In your case the time slot is 60 seconds and the operation is reading a certain number of feeds. Crashing is pretty drastic, but measuring is mandatory.

The simplest action to take is to start running multiple worker processes. Give some of your feeds to each process.  php runs single-threaded so multiple processes probably will help, at least until you get to three or four of them.

Then you will need to add another computer, and divide your feeds among worker processes on those multiple computers.

A language environment that parses JSON faster than php does might help, but only if the time it takes to parse the JSON is more important than the time it takes to wait for it to arrive.

Comment: This is a great write up. Thank you.

I had already been following a cycle quite similar to that, however what you have said as joined a few more dots. I'll take another look and see if I can refactor better.